How to pass a JWT through an Authorization header to +page.server.ts in SvelteKit
Recently I started developing my first big webapp project and I've decided I want to build it with SvelteKit. After some research I have discovered about authorization and authentication and I have decided to use a JSONWebToken to provide proper authorization in my project. So, after researching about SvelteKit it became very clear that I needed to create a +page.server.ts in my route's directory and export load and actions in which I will handle GET and POST requests from the client.
However, the project isn't necessarily going to be scoped to a webapp only, in the future I plan to create a mobile version of the app using Flutter or some other framework. That being said, it become obvious to me that I cannot have server-sided code present only in SvelteKit's load functions and actions object and that I need to create API endpoints which my apps will "fetch".
My problem arises from the fact that I have decided NOT to store the JWT on the client (browser) in any way shape or form. Meaning that the JWT only exists as an in-memory variable on the client once the user has been authenticated (and yes I know that hitting F5 will remove the token, don't worry this is expected behaviour to me). What I am trying to say is that I have no clue how I could send the authorization token to +page.server.ts...
So an example load function and actions object look like this:
export async function load({fetch, url, request}) {
    const headers = request.headers????
    const response = await fetch(myEndpoint)
    ...
    return (await response.json()).data
}

export const actions = {
    someAction: async ({ request, fetch }) => {
        const data = Object.fromEntries((await request.formData()).entries());
        const response = await fetch(myApiEndpoint, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
    }
};

Basically what is happening is that the client's request is being passed to the fetch() inside the load and actions and then after a response arrives the rest of the logic (which I didn't write here for the sake of simplicity) gets executed.
Again, my problem is authorizing these requests with a JWT from the client.
The ideal solution would be if I could somehow provide an Authorization: Bearer ${token} header to the request parameter of the load function and the async arrow function of every action.
Other solutions I am aware of:

Passing the token as a URL parameter => Firstly, I don't think this is a good idea from a security standpoint and secondly, I really don't want my URL to be a mess.
Passing the token with FormData for actions => Yeah, I am currently doing that for form actions, but it is not ideal.
Passing the token with an HttpOnly cookie => Not happening, I don't want any cookies, the JWT will only exist as an in-memory variable.
Not utilizing SvelteKit's form actions and load function => I know I can write my API calls in the +page.svelte and handle everything there, but then what's the point of using the framework at all...


As far as I know, SvelteKit does not provide a way for client-side code to add a header to HTTP requests the framework automatically sends from client. Instead, it relies on cookies for this type of thing. So if you don't want to use cookies, you probably need to add the JWT yourself to all the <a> and <form> elements.
